# AMIs snapshots without associated volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a few AMIs stored with snapshot associated with their storage definitions. However, the volumes that are associated with those snapshots have been deleted to save costs.

Can the AMIs still be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because snapshot is a **backup** of your volume. The original volume does not have to exist for the snapshot to be useful. You can always [create a volume from a snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-volume.html#ebs-create-volume-from-snapshot).

If you want to double check this, you can spin up basic t2.micro instance, take it snapshot, delete the instance and any associated volumes (root volume will be automatically deleted). Then you can launch new instance from the snapshot created.

Comment: So according to what you say, I can delete all the volumes associated with my AMIs, only keep the snapshots and still use the AMI? That does not make sense to me. Why would AWS create a volume in order to create the snapshot for the AMI - and keep it? That would create extra charges that are not needed.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams That the purpose of the snapshot, to keep backup of the volume. You can easily check it as I wrote in the answer if you want to make sure.

Comment: Why wouldn't Amazon delete the volume after creating the snapshot for the AMI? Sounds like an extra charge that is not needed.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Snapshot can't be used on the instance. Only volumes. If you delete volume, its snapshot can't be attached to any instance, can't be opened nor accessed. You have to have volume. Snapshots are backups only. It would be non-describable to delete volumes after taking snapshots.

Comment: I think my confusion is because I now understand AWS only creates a volume for the ROOT volume, not the other data disks. However, it still creates snapshots for all volumes specified in the AMI, for some reason!

Comment: @GilbertWilliams An AMI can be created from an existing instance. The AMI will contain snapshots of the disks associated with the instance. The instance itself will continue to run from its existing volumes. You ask "Why wouldn't Amazon delete the volume after creating the snapshot for the AMI" -- This is like asking "Why doesn't my computer backup software erase my hard disk after it has created a backup?" It's because people will still want to use their computer. They can, if they wish, terminate the instance and just keep the backup.